# Is there a way to declare a class and then define it later in c++?

Tags: c++, function, class, oop

So i want to declare a function *func(temp t1, temp t2)* and use it in *class temp*. But i do not want to define it as a member function of the *class temp* mainly because i want other functions to be able to access *func* without using any object of *temp*. I know it is possible by declaring *func()* as a friend to *temp* but is there a way to declare a sort of prototype for *temp* so that I can use it as arguments for a non member function *temp* and then define it later?

```
template<typename Type>
class record
{
    public:
    Type data;
    /*....some other memebers...*/
    friend int rec_comp(const record& r1, const record& r2)
    {

    }

    bool operator==(const record& r1, const record& r2)
    {
        if(rec_comp(r1, r2)==0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    /*...similar implementation for other relational operators ...*/
};
```

i want to declare the function *rec_comp* outside the class.

Comment: Do you mean like `class Foo;`? But it only works with references/pointers.

Comment: Then you have a bad implementation design.

Comment: yes. something like that is allowed?

Comment: @GauravShukla Then please create a small example with the desired use case. But I also smell some bad design

Comment: *Declare* it as a friend function inside the class, then *define* (implement) it outside the class? You can't call the function without the full class definition anyway, so might as well declare it in the class as a `friend` function.

Comment: what does it mean to "access func without using any object of temp" ?

Comment: On another couple of notes, `rec_comp` should probably return a `bool` value. And if you have `if (condition) return true; else return false;` then that's exactly the same as `return condition;`

Comment: `template <typename T> int rec_comp(record<T> const&, record<T> const&);`

Comment: the function rec_comp might retrun +ve or -ve values so that i can use the same rec_comp function to overload the '<' and '>' operators

Comment: If your compiler is new enough, consider using [three-way comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison) with the "spaceship" operator `<=>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. One example is given below:

**func.h**

```
#pragma once 

//declaration for class temp 
class Temp;

//declaration for function func 
void func(Temp t1, Temp t2);
```

**func.cpp**

```
#include "func.h"
#include "temp.h"
#include<iostream>
//implementation for function func 
void func(Temp t1, Temp t2)
{
    std::cout<<"func called"<<std::endl;
    //do something with t2 and t2 
}
```

**temp.h**

```
#pragma once 

//class definition
class Temp 
{
  int i = 0;  
  public:
  //default constructor
  Temp();//this is a declaration
};
```

**temp.cpp**

```
#include "temp.h"
#include <iostream>

//definition for default constructor
Temp::Temp()
{
    std::cout<<"default constructor called"<<std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "func.h"
#include "temp.h"
int main()
{
    Temp t1, t2;
    
    //call func 
    func(t1,t2);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/bcIGCye7B).

#### Edit

Since you have edited your question, below is the answer to your edited question.

```
template<typename Type>
class record
{
    public:
    Type data;
    
    //NOTE: rec_comp is NOT A MEMBER FUNCTION
    template<typename U, typename V> friend int rec_comp(const record<U>& r1, const record<V>& r2); //THIS IS A DECLARATION
    
   
};

//THIS IS A DEFINITION
template<typename U, typename V>
int rec_comp(const record<U>& r1, const record<V>& r2)
{
    return 5;
}
```

Comment: @GauravShukla You can make the `rec_comp` a `friend` of class `record` as shown in my above answer. I have edited my answer to answer your edited question. Check it out.

Comment: Bear in mind, with this approach, that not much is achieved by only including `func.h`.  In particular, it is insufficient if you need to define member functions of class `Temp`, create instances of `Temp`, or call the function `func()`.   In all those cases, it is necessary to ALSO include `temp.h`.   For example, remove the `#include "temp.h"` from `main.cpp`, and `main.cpp` will not compile.

Comment: @Peter Ofcourse i cannot discuss each and every possibility there is. I have just given one possible example according to what was described in the original question so that the OP can take it as a reference(starting point).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to declare a clss and then define it later in c++?

Yes. Simply omit the curly bracket delimited body of the class definition to get a non-defining declaration. This is declaration of a class:

```
class temp;
```

> declaring func() as a friend

Declaring function as a friend of class is only useful in allowing the friend function to access protected and private members and bases of the class.

> So i want to declare a function func(temp t1, temp t2) and use it in class temp.

Declaring the class (without definition) before declaring the function would indeed work. But it isn't strictly necessary. Alternative order that also works:

- define `temp`
- declare `func`
- define member functions of `temp` that use `func`

However, I do recommend the approach of declaring the class first. It's usually easiest to find a correct order by following the pattern of declare classes, declare functions, define classes, define functions.